# SweetAlert pop-up message with JavaScript when the fields are filled

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I wanted to make `Sweetalert` to work only if all the `fields` are filled. I tried more versions of code, I found answers here on the forum but nothing helped. Now if I do not fill all of the fields and I click on the `submit` I get notification message because of HTML, but the pop-up appears too.

[As you can see here, altough I got the pop-up, I did not fill the last input field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKRuz.jpg)

```
function Sweetalert1(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var message = document.getElementById("message");
    var email = document.getElementById("email");

    if ((name != "" && message != "" && email != "") {
        Swal.fire(
                'Köszönjük!',
                'Megkaptuk a leveledet és hamarosan válaszolunk!',
                'success'

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value of your form inputs. Currently, your `name`, `message` and `email` are all [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)s and thus none of them equal `""`. So your `if` statement really looks like:

```
if (true && true && true) {
  // code..
}
```

Instead, you can get the values from your input elements:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
```

This way you are getting the text inputted into the input fields, not the elements themselves.