# Sweetalert PoP-up message when fields are field is not working

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert

I had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724615/sweetalert-pop-up-when-the-fields-are-filled) about Sweetalert a week ago. Then I got an answer which helped me, but unfortunately, it is still not working. I wanted a Sweetalert pop-up message (success) when the user hits the submit button, but only if the fields are filled. I do not know what the problem is. Currently, nothing happens when the user hits the button.

Here is my code:

```
function Sweetalert1(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

    if (name != " " && message != " " && email != " "){
        Swal.fire(
                'Köszönjük!',
                'Megkaptuk a leveledet és hamarosan válaszolunk!',
                'success',
    )}
}
```

And the part of the HTML:

```
<form role="form" id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                        <label>Név</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Név" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Kérlek add meg a neved!">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                        <label>Email Cím</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" data-validation-required-message="Kérlek add meg az Email címed!">
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                        <label>Üzenet</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Üzenet" name="message" required data-validation-required-message="Kérlek írd be az üzeneted!"></textarea>
                        <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" id="sendMessageButton">Küldés</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: The main problem here is that I see nothing at all that links the form to your `Sweetalert1` function. Here's fixed example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/2utezwcb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see where the button was fired

On this line,

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" id="sendMessageButton">Küldés</button>
```

You have at least two options to fire the button

**1st**

You can change the line to this

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" id="sendMessageButton" onclick="Sweetalert1()">Küldés</button>
```

**2nd**

You can add this to your javascript section

```
$("#sendMessageButton").click(function(){
    Sweetalert1();
});
```

**3rd**

You can use the form's on-submit event

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    Sweetalert1();
});
```

When this is done, modify your condition to

```
if (name !== "" && message !== "" && email !== "")
```

OR

```
if (name.trim() && message.trim() && email.trim())
```

Answer (score 1):

your condition is not right, try doing this:

```
if (name && message && email)
{
   // Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty field isn't equal to a space (`" "`), it is equal to an empty string (`""`). So, you need to check if the fields equal an empty string, not a field with a space:

```
if (name != "" && message != "" && email != "") {
  // code...
}
```

However, if you want to treat fields which have no text in them (and just spaces) as invalid as well, you can add the `.trim()` method to your `name`, `message` and `email` variables. By using trim you can turn inputs such as 
 `"        "` into `""`, which will then be treated as an invalid input:

```
if (name.trim() != "" && message.trim() != "" && email.trim() != "") {
  // code...
}
```

As an empty string is considered `falsey` (ie `"" == false`) you don't need to check whether you're input equals an empty string and instead can just check if `x.trim()` evaluates to `true` like so:

```
if (name.trim() && message.trim() && email.trim()) {
  // code...
}
```